# Limit the number of Get-ChildItem results

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script that will log the changes to the modification date of a specific file. I only care about the single newest file. I want to capture that and save its name and `Lastwritetime` to a text file.

I am only finding results limiting recursion.

Is there a way to limit the number of results?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use the Select-Object:

```
Get-ChildItem . | Select-Object -last 1
```

If you want the latest file, something like:

```
Get-ChildItem . | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | select -last 1
```

And of course you can get only the properties that you are interested in with Select-Object as well:

```
Get-ChildItem .  | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -last 1 Name,LastWriteTime
```

And you can pipe that to [Export-Csv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Export-Csv).

Aliases can also be used, `Get-ChildItem` → `gci`, `Select-Object` → `select`, and `Sort-Object` → `sort`.

Comment: @Legends `Select-Object -Last 10` ?

Comment: For the head of the results instead of the tail use -First with select.

Comment: Does this avoid getting all files in a directory? I have a huuuuuuuge number of files, and only want to get X at a time....

Comment: @AndrewRalon I'm sure by now you know, but for anyone in the future, I had the same question. And if you use "-First x", then yes - it will only get the first 10 results. Even if you have a bunch of | Where-Objects | then the Select-Object at the end, it will get the first 10 results that match your query, then continue the script.